# multiple signature verification on solana smart contract

Tags: anchor, solana-program

I have a question about verifying multiple signatures in a Solana smart contract. Let's say I have a 'hello' message that has been signed by multiple key pairs using nacl.sign.detached with the Solana ed25519 program. How can I verify both the message and the multiple signatures within the Solana smart contract? also i have explored ho to do it signle signer i want to know how can do it multiple signer

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I entirely understand the question, but if you are using Anchor, you can add `Signer`s to your Accounts Context:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = payer, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub data_account: Account<'info, MyData>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub co_signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

In this example, your `co_signer` will be required to sign the transaction. You would probably want some other constraint in your context to define which or instruction to define which signer's are allowed.